# Write data continuously to file in external storage - Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, fileoutputstream, android-external-storage

I am writing the data to the file in an external storage (SD card) on my android. The issue that I am facing is that it just makes one entry and does not go beyond that. I have looked up a number of Q/As here. Could someone please point me in the write direction? TIA!

```
FileOutputStream outputstream;
try {
    file1 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyData.txt");
    outputstream = new FileOutputStream(file1);
    OutputStreamWriter oswriter = new OutputStreamWriter(outputstream);
    BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter (oswriter);
    bwriter.append(entry);
    bwriter.newLine();
    bwriter.close();
    outputstream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what is your problem. The code you posted will do exactly what you described.

Comment: @m0skit0 - I am sorry if I was not very clear. The thing is I am continuously gathering data with my app and I would like to have all entries in the txt file. However, only the first entry gets added to the file and rest are not. I can however see in the logs that data is being fetched but somehow, the file does not add after first entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell `FileOutputStream` to append the data. By default it just overwrites all contents there. For this you only need to use a different constructor [`FileOutputStream(File, boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream(java.io.File,%20boolean)):

```
outputstream = new FileOutputStream(file1, true);
```

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much for your help, tynn.